# Bounding box of set of MULTILINESTRINGs in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, linestring, extents

I have a PostGIS table with a geometry column (`geom`) and a `type` column. The `geom` column contains only `MULTILINESTRINGs` and the `type` column contains tags that tell me what each `MULTILINESTRING` represents. The tags are just letters. I’m trying to get the bounding box of all the `MULTILINESTRINGs` in the table that have `type='a'`.
I tried the following but it does not work:

```
SELECT *
FROM line_table
WHERE line_table.geom && SELECT ST_Envelope(line_table.geom) FROM line_table WHERE type='a';
```

I’m new to PostGIS and SQL in general so I’m not sure if I’m even close to the answer. Right now I think the problem is that I'm getting one independent envelope for each `MULTILINESTRING` where `type='a'` instead of the bounding box of all the `MULTILINESTRINGs` together. Perhaps there is a way of merging all the `MULTILINESTRINGs` of `type='a'` into one geometry but so far I have not been able to figure out how.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [ST_Envelope()](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Envelope.html) function operates on single geometries, therefore you are right, you need aggregate  your MULTILINESTRINGs before you pass them by St_Envelope(). [St_Collect()](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html) is a good aggregation function for that job.

```sql
SELECT ST_Envelope(st_Collects(foo.geom))
FROM line_table as foo
WHERE foo.type='a';
```

If you want to retrieve the bounding box for each different value of the "type" column in one single statement,  then you would need to use the GROUP BY. Something like this:

```sql
SELECT foo.type, ST_Envelope(st_Collects(foo.geom))
FROM line_table as foo
GROUP BY foo.type;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on Alexandre's answer, as of at least version 2.3.2, PostGIS now **does** allow you to get a bounding box from multi geometries.

```
SELECT st_astext(
         st_envelope(
           'MULTILINESTRING((0 0, 1 1), (2 2, 3 3))'::geometry))
```

There is also the [Box2D](https://postgis.net/docs/Box2D.html) function, which serves the same purpose, but also works with other types of geometries such as curves, surfaces and TIN. They also perform the same, even for large datasets.